# my aspx.cs doesn't see my runat="server" controls

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem: I don't know what happened, but suddenly my `Home.aspx.cs` doesn't see my `runat="server"` controls from `Home.aspx`. Here is some code from `Home.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page"
    Language="C#"
    MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"
    AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent"
    runat="server"
    ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>

<input type="hidden"
    id="ascuns" runat="server" />

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" 
    runat="server"
    ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
</asp:Content>
```

And in my `Home.aspx.cs`, I get the error: "The name ascuns does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 1):

The `Inherits` attribute of your `@Page` directive is wrong. It should read `Inherits="Home"` instead of  `Inherits="_Default"`.

Keep in mind that the `CodeFile` attribute is not used by the ASP.NET server, only by the Visual Studio Solution Explorer to prevent the .aspx.cs files from cluttering up the file list. The ASP.NET server uses either the `Inherits` or the `ClassName` attribute to link the page markup to the right page class.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try placing the hidden field inside the BodyContent placeholder and verify?
i.e.

< asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent"> < /asp:Content>  < asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"> **< input type="hidden" id="ascuns" runat="server" />**< /asp:Content>

Since the Home.aspx is a content page, that might be causing the issue.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake : I had another page that had the code behind Home.aspx.cs and that generated that error .